# Variance-covariance matrix for structural parameters in simultaneous equation models

Tags: mathematical-statistics, econometrics, feature-engineering

The structural form of the linear simultaneous equations model [simultaneous equations model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_equations_model) can
be written as

$
\mathbf{y}_{i}^{\prime}\Gamma+\mathbf{x}_{i}^{\prime}\mathbf{B}=\epsilon_{i}^{\prime}
$

which can be written in the reduced form model as

$
\mathbf{y}_{i}^{\prime}  =-\mathbf{x}_{i}^{\prime}\mathbf{B}\Gamma^{-1}+\epsilon_{i}^{\prime}\Gamma^{-1}\\
=\mathbf{x}_{i}^{\prime}\Pi+\mathbf{v}_{i}^{\prime}.
$

The reduced form model can be estimated with different estimation methods and if the model is identified the structural coefficients $\widehat{\mathbf{B}}$ can be obtained by using the relation $\widehat{\mathbf{B}}=\widehat{\Pi}\widehat{\Gamma}$.

I wonder how to drive the variance-covariance matrix of $\widehat{\mathbf{B}}$. I'd highly appreciate if you point out me any reference. Thanks in advance for your help and time.

Comment: It would help if you'd define the terms in your equations. Also, is $\widehat{{\bf B}}$ a maximum likelihood estimator (if so, under what assumptions) or..?

Comment: Thanks @Macro for your notice. Please see the link for complete information about the model. Thanks again for your interest.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure your question can be answered in the generality you posed it. If you are estimating $\widehat{\mathbf B}$ using equation-by-equation instrumental variables, then the latter method provides for the standard errors based on the explicit expression of the IV estimator. If you have full information maximum likelihood, then you don't use the reduced form, and just keep things in the structural form, so (i) you don't get to this complication of having to disentangle $\widehat{\mathbf \Pi}$ to get the $\widehat{\mathbf B}$ parameters out of them, and (ii) you get the standard errors out of the inverse Hessian, as usual. So the question of how to get the standard errors really depends on the estimation method.

[Davidson and MacKinnon's EIE (1993)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0195060113) is an indispensable resource.